# Merging Changes from Master to Remote branch in git

Tags: git, merge

I have created remote branch name REMOTE1 and made changes and updated the REMOTE1. Similarly my colleagues have worked on MASTER and made considerable amount of changes.

Now I have to merge the changes from remote/MASTER to remote/REMOTE1.

Can anyone help me with the best workflow to follow in this case. I have tried following steps

```
git checkout master

git pull

git checkout REMOTE1

git rebase master
```

So many merge conflicts and I have resolved them ...

when I try git status

```
# On branch REMOTE1
# Your branch and 'origin/REMOTE1' have diverged,
# and have 16 and 10 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
```

I am not sure what it means ???

Then I try to PUSH into my remote branch REMOTE1 and I get following error

```
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> REMOTE1 (non-fast-forward)
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Before any rebase operation

```
--- A - B - C - D   MASTER
         \
         P - Q - R  REMOTE1
```

After doing the steps mentioned above

```
              MASTER     LOCAL REMOTE1
                |           |
--- A - B - C - D - P - Q - R    
        \
         P - Q - R   REMOTE1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to push REMOTE1 with different changes than the ones that are on origin/REMOTE1. Before doing this, try to pull REMOTE1. First, check it out:

```
git checkout REMOTE1
```

Now, while on REMOTE1, pull the changes from `origin`:

```
git pull origin REMOTE1
```

Now you have local REMOTE1 synchronized with origin/REMOTE1. You can rebase changes from master and push:

```
git checkout master
git rebase REMOTE1
git checkout REMOTE1
git push origin REMOTE1
```

Comment: I have exactly followed your steps .. Did a new clone and then checkout REMOTE1 .. did a pull origin REMOTE1 ... then rebase master .. After that git status shows the same diverged as I mentioned earlier ... git push origin REMOTE1 also shows the same error ...

Comment: I changed commands a bit, but it shouldn't matter. Looks like you have made some changes to REMOTE1 after cloning/ pulling it?  Is P-Q-R  same what is on origin/REMOTE1? Can you successfully push before rebasing? Rebase does not change this branch, does it?

Comment: As per your new commands .. I have to rebase my master with REMOTE1 and then checkout REMOTE1 and do a PUSH operation ?

Comment: It depends what you need to achieve. As far as I understood, you want to move your local changes from master to REMOTE1 and push them, right? If that's the case, yes, you have to rebase your changes from MASTER to REMOTE1 and push it.